# PHP - using operators to compare array values

Tags: php, arrays, operators, compare

If I have an array:

```
$array = array ( [rock] => 40, [pop] => 30, [rap] => 20 ) etc...
```

how can I do something like:

```
foreach key in $array 
{
if (array_value > 30) echo "> 30:" . $array_key . "<br>";
if (array_value < 30) echo "< 30:" . $array_key . "<br>";
}
```

So that the result would be:

```
> 30:rock<br>
< 30:pop<br>
< 30:rap<br>
```

Thanks! I hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if      ($value ...) echo $key...
    else if ($value ...) echo $key...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !! I rarely use foreach loops with arrays but now I understand them. Thanks again!

Comment: Should be `elseif` (no space).

Comment: @Mike `else if` works just fine and exactly the same way and is IMO more readable.

Comment: Guess it's preference. `else if` indicates that the `if` may have an accompanying `elseif` or `else`, whereas if you wrote it as `elseif` there is no confusion.

Comment: @Mike Sorry, I'm confused what you're getting confused about... :)

Answer (score 2):

deceze's answer is correct in general, but more specifically, the following code should work:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value > 30) {
        echo '> 30:' . $key . '<br>';
    } elseif ($value <= 30) { // Changed this to <= to cover the case of $value = 30
        echo '< 30:' . $key . '<br>';
    }
}
```